# App Build Successfully , But Archive error in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, archive

I am developing one iOS product which has many files and third party libraries used with cocoapods. We have developed app in Swift 2.3 . Now we have started conversation to Swift 3 ,We have updated all cocoapod libraries and fixed all issues. We can run app in Device as well as simulator . Now i want to prepare ipa to my client ,but I am getting below error while archiving app. Can any one help me to come from out from this ?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_F3IBNG29NETWORK_PROFILE_CORNER_RADIUSV12CoreGraphics7CGFloat", referenced from:
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of abc.abcViewController.tableView (__ObjC.UITableView, cellForRowAt : Foundation.IndexPath) -> __ObjC.UITableViewCell in abcViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

[image]

Comment: Have you cleaned the app's build with cmd-shift-k?

Comment: @BallpointBen  : Yes already Done . also try to clean build folder and DerivedData.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: @BallpointBen  : Not helpful because it builds successfully and archive in swift 2.3 with xcode7.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)