# How to correctly include C++ static library to iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, linker

I have a project which contains C++ static library (mylib.a), header for it (mylib.h) and objc class which use functions of this library (*.h/*.m).
I'm trying to copy this files to another project but every time I'm getting linking error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7
_ClassNameFromLibrary
referenced from:
      -[LibraryUserClass init] in LibraryUserClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This library works correctly in another project. I tried to copy all setting from working project and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing file `myclass.m` to `myclass.mm`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `libxml2.dylib` and `libz.dylib` In Link Binary With Libraries.

If that does not work, please refer this question answer: [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: It doesn't help me. Fixed another way. Look my answer