# iOS manually exporting library causes issues

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I made a library and I want to test it in a dummy project I made. Both projects are made in Objective-C. When I build my library I get a *Successful Build* message and three files under the **Product** directory:

1. FooIOS.bundle
2. libFooIOS.a
3. include

I place these three files at the **root** level of my dummy project and when I open my **myDummyProject.xcworkspace** file I see them in my project hierarchy. However, when I build my project I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FooSelectedPageViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFooIOS.a(FooViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did away with some of the obvious checks:

- Made sure to reference my external library

[image]

- I also made sure that both my library and project architectures are set as **armv7 arm64**

I don't know what else to do. I may be missing another configuration step or it may even be the way I declared something in my library that doesn't conform with my dummy project. Or a discrepancy between projects, perhaps? Any hints or leads would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the path to the library to `Library Search Paths` under Build Settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: @CinderBiscuits how do I check if I added the path to the library. I'm still learning the ins and outs of XCode