# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 in Xcode after import from Unity3D

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, arm

i export my project from Unity3D to Xcode.

In Unity my project has so many library such as : **Facebook SDK**,PlayMaker,Easy Save,Dotween,etc

I try to build my Xcode project but failed. it give me error :

**"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"**

or **"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"**

i have try a solution by changing architecture to armv64, but same error appear :

**"Undefined symbols for architecture armv64"**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_ui", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_ui_m1731210125 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _Unityplcrash_async_mobject_read_uint64, _Unityplcrash_async_mobject_read_uint16 , _png_get_uint_32 , _UNITY_png_get_uint_31 , _stbir_resize_uint16_generic , _stbir_resize_uint8_generic , _stbir_resize_uint8 , _Unityplcrash_async_task_read_uint32 , _plcrash_async_task_read_uint16 , _plcrash_async_task_read_uint8 , _uintUniformFuncs , _ES2_uint_t4107039728_0_0_0 , _ES2_uint_t4107039728_1_0_0 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_m3650485187_gp_0_0_0_0 , _ES3Type_uintArray_t2844838656_0_0_0 , _Unityplcrash_async_mobject_read_uint32 , _stbir_resize_uint8_srgb , _png_get_uint_16 , _ES3Type_uintArray_t2844838656_1_0_0 , _UNITY_png_save_uint_32 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionType_t2820876680_m2982207170_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMinMaxCurve_t1067599125_m2985702734_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisWrapMode_t730450702_m3264025746_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector2_t2156229523_m2041756521_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextureFormat_t2701165832_m1540843842_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextAnchor_t2035777396_m4132546558_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisStereoTargetEyeMask_t1137745477_m1175819693_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisSkinQuality_t4231844520_m2458564879_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisSingle_t1397266774_m1917433571_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRenderingPath_t883966888_m2647692778_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisPhysicMaterialCombine_t247666954_m2068942797_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemTrailTextureMode_t3780115444_m1421931053_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemSimulationSpace_t2969500608_m647009106_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemShapeType_t4289797000_m2982566186_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemNoiseQuality_t2264279745_m4217837034_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCurveMode_t3859704052_m3642036119_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionQuality_t378369488_m2233775747_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionMode_t1606691222_m2087247994_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemAnimationType_t3289377710_m2964003998_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMotionVectorGenerationMode_t582917276_m3148873913_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMinMaxCurve_t1067599125_m2985702734_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMatrix4x4_t1817901843_m519299212_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags_t172918339_m3535238437_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightProbeUsage_t800497123_m2956380566_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisInt32_t2950945753_m357389674_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisHorizontalWrapMode_t2172737147_m25992474_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisCameraType_t2859855855_m3640304708_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisCameraClearFlags_t2362496923_m2968698873_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVerticalWrapMode_t2936607737_m4008660850_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisWrapMode_t730450702_m3264025746_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector4_t3319028937_m3584887243_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextureWrapMode_t584250749_m232699000_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisSkinQuality_t4231844520_m2458564879_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightProbeUsage_t800497123_m2956380566_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemShapeType_t4289797000_m2982566186_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemScalingMode_t2278533876_m1262199072_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemNoiseQuality_t2264279745_m4217837034_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemMeshShapeType_t1986719567_m1845125516_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemGradientMode_t862789074_m1218940207_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionQuality_t378369488_m2233775747_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionMode_t1606691222_m2087247994_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemAnimationType_t3289377710_m2964003998_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMinMaxGradient_t3677460847_m4056765274_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMatrix4x4_t1817901843_m519299212_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightType_t1494112716_m1365838454_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightRenderMode_t1384513348_m4083600620_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLayerMask_t3493934918_m174135517_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisHorizontalWrapMode_t2172737147_m25992474_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisColor_t2555686324_m1259725901_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisCameraType_t2859855855_m3640304708_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisSingle_t1397266774_m1917433571_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRuntimeObject_m3090677384_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisInt32_t2950945753_m357389674_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemInheritVelocityMode_t1008988385_m771248766_MetadataUsageId , _stbir_resize_uint8_srgb_edgemode , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLayerMask_t3493934918_m174135517_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_t202586196_1_0_0 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRenderingPath_t883966888_m2647692778_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags_t172918339_m3535238437_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisPhysicMaterialCombine_t247666954_m2068942797_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisStereoTargetEyeMask_t1137745477_m1175819693_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightShadows_t1089484200_m1319638519_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_t202586196_0_0_0 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisShadowCastingMode_t2280965600_m3707650513_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVerticalWrapMode_t2936607737_m4008660850_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisColor_t2555686324_m1259725901_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisDepthTextureMode_t4161834719_m1042633232_MetadataUsageId , _CanvasScaler_set_uiScaleMode_m2475900918 , _CanvasScaler_get_uiScaleMode_m1035769874 , _UNITY_png_save_uint_16 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCurveMode_t3859704052_m3642036119_gshared , _InlineGraphicManager_get_uiVertex_m2616979326 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightShadowResolution_t3029073116_m88710492_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemScalingMode_t2278533876_m1262199072_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightRenderMode_t1384513348_m4083600620_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisCameraClearFlags_t2362496923_m2968698873_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightType_t1494112716_m1365838454_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRuntimeObject_m3090677384_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisBounds_t2266837910_m75645703_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemOverlapAction_t2023522131_m2414515044_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemCollisionType_t2820876680_m2982207170_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisOpaqueSortMode_t868829811_m4081542433_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemOverlapAction_t2023522131_m2414515044_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisUVChannelFlags_t2414221641_m899369362_MetadataUsageId , _ES2_uint__ctor_m2959526607 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisShadowCastingMode_t2280965600_m3707650513_gshared , _ES3JSONReader_Read_uint_m2968934393 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMinMaxGradient_t3677460847_m4056765274_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisFilterMode_t3761284007_m2496598921_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisReflectionProbeUsage_t3366161812_m2259898281_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextureWrapMode_t584250749_m232699000_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisFontStyle_t82229486_m2202335904_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisInt64_t3736567304_m3270286583_MetadataUsageId , _Unityplcrash_async_task_read_uint64 , _ES2_uint__ctor_m2959526607_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisMotionVectorGenerationMode_t582917276_m3148873913_gshared , _ES3Type_uint__ctor_m3748426561 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisInt64_t3736567304_m3270286583_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemTrailTextureMode_t3780115444_m1421931053_gshared , _ES2_uint_t4107039728_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTransparencySortMode_t3644896537_m2720743446_gshared , _ES2_uint_Read_m345373705 , _ES3Type_uintArray__ctor_m1239549541_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector3_t3722313464_m961987674_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisOpaqueSortMode_t868829811_m4081542433_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemInheritVelocityMode_t1008988385_m771248766_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisFilterMode_t3761284007_m2496598921_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRect_t2360479859_m3821692247_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_t202586196_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisHideFlags_t4250555765_m402785864_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Write_m1173633626 , _ES3Type_uint__cctor_m2853086174 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisGradientMode_t16368456_m2283165443_gshared , _CanvasJSWrapper_ui_m1731210125 , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector2_t2156229523_m2041756521_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisByte_t1134296376_m1686910887_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisUVChannelFlags_t2414221641_m899369362_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTransparencySortMode_t3644896537_m2720743446_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisQuaternion_t2301928331_m549888546_gshared , _ES3Type_uintArray_t2844838656_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector3_t3722313464_m961987674_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisHideFlags_t4250555765_m402785864_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint__ctor_m3748426561_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextAnchor_t2035777396_m4132546558_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisFontStyle_t82229486_m2202335904_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisBoolean_t97287965_m2088095745_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightShadowResolution_t3029073116_m88710492_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisRect_t2360479859_m3821692247_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisLightShadows_t1089484200_m1319638519_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisByte_t1134296376_m1686910887_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisReflectionProbeUsage_t3366161812_m2259898281_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisQuaternion_t2301928331_m549888546_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisBoolean_t97287965_m2088095745_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisBounds_t2266837910_m75645703_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemMeshShapeType_t1986719567_m1845125516_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemSimulationSpace_t2969500608_m647009106_gshared , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisTextureFormat_t2701165832_m1540843842_gshared , _Unityplcrash_async_mobject_read_uint8 , _ES2_uint_Read_m345373705_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisParticleSystemGradientMode_t862789074_m1218940207_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisVector4_t3319028937_m3584887243_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisDepthTextureMode_t4161834719_m1042633232_gshared , _ES2_uint_Write_m846852357_MetadataUsageId , _ES3Type_uint_Read_TisGradientMode_t16368456_m2283165443_MetadataUsageId , _ES2_uint_Write_m846852357 , _ES3Type_uintArray__ctor_m1239549541 , _ES3Type_uint_Write_m1173633626_MetadataUsageId )
  "_activateApp", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_ActivateApp_m2243162300 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
      _CanvasJSWrapper_activateApp_m160690348 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _CanvasJSWrapper_activateApp_m160690348)
  "_initScreenPosition", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_InitScreenPosition_m4169447146 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
      _CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_m891649343 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_m891649343)
  "_logPurchase", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_logPurchase_m2329488507 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _CanvasJSWrapper_logPurchase_m2329488507)
  "_logout", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_Logout_m88830784 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
      _CanvasJSWrapper_logout_m2238411584 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _CanvasJSWrapper_logout_m2238411584)
  "_init", referenced from:
      _CanvasJSWrapper_init_m2214171880 in Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.o
     (maybe you meant: _cf2_arrstack_init, _cf2_stack_init , _cf2_hintmask_init , _cf2_blues_init , _vp8_mb_init_dequantizer , _cf2_initLocalRegionBuffer , _cf2_initGlobalRegionBuffer , _cff_parser_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21TilemapRefCountedDataI10ColorRGBAfELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21TilemapRefCountedDataI10Matrix4x4fELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21TilemapRefCountedDataI4PPtrI6ObjectEELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEN3Alg13UserAllocatorIcEEE6__initIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ , _sfnt_init_face , _t1_hints_funcs_init , _cff_driver_init , _cff_size_init , _cff_slot_init , _fmod_tremor_buffer_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIPN5physx12PxRigidActorELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS2_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN19TilemapRendererJobs21SharedRenderChunkData15RenderChunkDataELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _UNITY_tt_face_init , _UNITY_tt_size_init , _UNITY_tt_slot_init , _FMOD_vorbis_book_init_decode , _FMOD_ogg_stream_init , _il2cpp_init_utf16 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI22DirectorGenericBindingLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _initialTime , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN27AnimationLayerMixerPlayable15LayerParametersELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN15MetalDynamicVBO20MetalDynamicVBOChunkELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , _FMOD_vorbis_block_init , __FMOD_vorbis_window_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI10CrowdAgentLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayItLm2EE18resize_initializedEmRKt12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI11TangentInfoLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIbLm1EE18resize_initializedEmRKb12ResizePolicy , __Z36imageblock_initialize_work_from_origP10imageblocki , __Z46imageblock_initialize_deriv_from_work_and_origP10imageblocki , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIhLm16EE18resize_initializedEmRKh12ResizePolicy , __Z36imageblock_initialize_orig_from_workP10imageblocki , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN23ReflectionProbesContext23ReflectionProbeCubeInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIP15LODGroupManagerLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __ZN4crnd12symbol_codec13get_bits_initEv , _Unityplcrash_async_macho_symtab_reader_init , _Unityplcrash_async_mobject_init , _Unityplcrash_async_objc_cache_init , _UNITY_ft_validator_init , _GC_dirty_init , _GC_init_size_map , _GC_explicit_typing_initialized , _GC_init_explicit_typing , _GC_mark_init , _GC_initiate_gc , _GC_initialize_offsets , _GC_init_headers , _GC_thr_init , _GC_init , _GC_init_gcj_malloc , _plcrash_nasync_macho_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIPS_IfLm4EELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN13VideoPlayback15AudioOutputInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN8LODGroup3LODELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _Unityplcrash_async_macho_string_init , __ZN9b2Contact13s_initializedE , __Z63Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_set_initializationModev , __Z63Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_get_initializationModev , __Z73Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_INTERNAL_get_initializationColorv , __Z65Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_set_initializationSourcev , __Z65Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_get_initializationSourcev , __Z67Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_set_initializationMaterialv , __Z14kpp_initializeiiiiPK10imageblockP6vtype4IfE , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI5RectTIfELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPKcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeESA_SA_ , _il2cpp_runtime_object_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN2UI8UIVertexELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN4core17string_with_labelILi35EEELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN20TextRenderingPrivate8FontImpl13CharacterInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI15ComputeShaderCBLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI27ComputeShaderBuiltinSamplerLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI19ComputeShaderKernelLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI20ComputeShaderVariantLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21AnimationClipOverrideLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN9ShaderLab21SerializedBindChannelELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIPN11UnityEngine9Animation23CachedComponentBindingsELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS3_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI16BlendShapeVertexLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI7SubMeshLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI10MinMaxAABBLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI13HeightmapDataLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _protobuf_c_service_generated_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI12LightmapDataLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI26EnlightenSystemInformationLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI8JobFenceLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayImLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIfLm16EE18resize_initializedEmRKf12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN21ExecutionOrderManager25DefaultExecutionOrderInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN11UnityEngine9Animation14GenericBindingELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI12PPtrKeyframeLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI11KeyframeTplI8Vector3fELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI18ComputeShaderParamLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN4math14float3_storageELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , _il2cpp_runtime_object_init_exception , _il2cpp_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI17SortingLayerEntryLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI18ScriptingMethodPtrLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIjLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKj12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN10GameObject13ComponentPairELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI5RectTIiELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _GC_gcj_malloc_initialized , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIS_I8Vector2fLm4EELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN19CompositeCollider2D11SubColliderELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI11KeyframeTplIfELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _Unityplframe_cursor_init , _Unityplcrash_async_symbol_cache_init , _Unityplcrash_async_thread_state_mach_thread_init , _plcrash_async_thread_state_init , __Z21scripting_object_init18ScriptingObjectPtr , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI10ResolutionLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __Z59CustomRenderTexture_CUSTOM_INTERNAL_set_initializationColorP12Il2CppObjectRK10ColorRGBAf , __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_ , _Unityplcrash_async_file_init , _Unityplcrash_async_thread_state_mcontext_init , _plcrash_nasync_image_list_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIPK26opaqueMTAudioProcessingTapLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS2_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI15DirectAudioInfoLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADNMemoryUtilizationMonitor._initiallyAllocatedByteCount , _il2cpp_runtime_class_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN21SimpleMediaAttributes14AudioTrackInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADNNetworkLogger._initialMessage , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIhLm1EE18resize_initializedEmRKh12ResizePolicy , _t2_hints_funcs_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI31EnlightenSystemAtlasInformationLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEN3Alg13UserAllocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcm , __Z67Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_get_initializationMaterialv , _Unityplcrash_log_writer_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN9SubModule14SubEmitterDataELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _cf2_hintmap_init , __Z76Register_UnityEngine_Advertisements_UnityAdsSettings_set_initializeOnStartupv , _MadSprite_set_initialSize_m941215146 , _unity_z__tr_init , _GC_bl_init_no_interiors , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN4core12basic_stringIcNS0_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _StackTrace_init_frames_m641783388 , _ps_hints_init , _vp8_loop_filter_frame_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI20BoundCurveDeprecatedLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _ExecuteEvents_get_initializePotentialDrag_m298985714_MetadataUsageId , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21PlatformShaderDefinesLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _GC_init_parallel , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI14OcclusionSceneLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _CanvasJSWrapper_init_m2214171880 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI28EnlightenRendererInformationLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI11KeyframeTplI11QuaternionfELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _StackTrace_init_frames_m641783388_MetadataUsageId , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21ComputeShaderResourceLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _FMOD_vorbis_synthesis_init , _IAPManager__init_m1547487051 , _Thread_Thread_init_m3583989169 , __ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System9Threading6Thread11Thread_initEP12Il2CppThread , _UNITY_tt_driver_init , _FMOD_mdct_init , __Z59CustomRenderTexture_CUSTOM_INTERNAL_get_initializationColorP12Il2CppObjectP10ColorRGBAf , _vp8_loop_filter_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI20TransformMaskElementLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _UNITY_png_init_read_transformations , _GC_bl_init , _MonoGenericClass_initialize_m2888890279_MetadataUsageId , _MonoGenericClass_initialize_m2888890279 , __ZN9ASTCCodec17codec_initializedE , _ModuleBuilder_basic_init_m3240533393 , __ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System10Reflection4Emit13ModuleBuilder10basic_initEP29Il2CppReflectionModuleBuilder , _GenericTypeParameterBuilder_initialize_m1360525264 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN19CustomRenderTexture14UpdateZoneInfoELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _Advertisement_get_initializeOnStartup_m827867793 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIS_I8Vector2fLm4EELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADOStoreKitProductAnimationData._initialStoreKitFrame , _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADOVideoAnimationData._initialVideoFrame , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI23DirectorSceneReferencesLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _MonoGenericClass_initialize_m1627935302 , _EventTrigger_set_initTime_m3128947762 , _AssemblyBuilder_basic_init_m1526438565 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI16SplashScreenLogoLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIP17ClippedDetailMeshLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , _SslHandshakeHash_initializePad_m1074089276 , _HMAC_initializePad_m59014980_MetadataUsageId , _UnityAdsSettings_get_initializeOnStartup_m4135646069 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN5Unity5Cloth26ClothConstrainCoefficientsELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI12BoneWeights4Lm16EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , _MadFont_get_initialized_m2512845942 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI9InputAxisLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIP17IAnimationBindingLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __Z73Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_INTERNAL_set_initializationColorv , _psh_globals_funcs_init , _cf2_glyphpath_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayINSt3__14pairIi12ImmediatePtrIN5Unity9ComponentEEEELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _jpeg_mem_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIsLm2EE18resize_initializedEmRKs12ResizePolicy , __Z66Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_get_initializationTexturev , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI19LightProbeOcclusionLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _FMOD_vorbis_info_init , _cff_face_init , __Z76Register_UnityEngine_Advertisements_UnityAdsSettings_get_initializeOnStartupv , _StackTrace_init_frames_m641783388_RuntimeMethod_var , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI21TilemapRefCountedDataI4PPtrI6SpriteEELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _vpx_codec_dec_init_ver , _WinRTStore_init_m2286003365 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI13ProbeSetIndexLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _cff_decoder_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIiLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKi12ResizePolicy , _gad_initnotification , _FMOD_ogg_sync_init , _Page_set_initialPosition_m1302445411 , _g_il2cpp_is_fully_initialized , _UNITY_png_init_io , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN16GeometryJobTasks15GeometryJobTaskELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIfLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKf12ResizePolicy , _WinRTStore_init_m2286003365_MetadataUsageId , _EventTrigger_get_initTime_m3511193067 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayINSt3__14pairI4PPtrI14SphereColliderES4_EELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _IAPManager__init_m1547487051_MetadataUsageId , _SslHandshakeHash_initializePad_m1074089276_MetadataUsageId , _GC_is_initialized , _HMAC_initializePad_m59014980 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIPhLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI27ParticleSystemEmissionBurstLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _vp8cx_init_de_quantizer , _ExecuteEvents_get_initializePotentialDrag_m298985714 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN14SerializedFile14SerializedTypeELm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS1_12ResizePolicy , _CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_m891649343 , _MadSprite_get_initialSize_m833555974 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI10BlendShapeLm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __Z66Register_UnityEngine_CustomRenderTexture_set_initializationTexturev , __ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System10Reflection4Emit15AssemblyBuilder10basic_initEP47mscorlib_System_Reflection_Emit_AssemblyBuilder , _Page_get_initialPosition_m3545871619 , _vp8_init_mbmode_probs , _GC_thr_initialized , _plcrash__crash_report__init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI22GenericDynamicVBOChunkLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , _UNITY_png_info_init_3 , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN11UnityEngine15CloudWebService14DataErrorEvent15FileErrorDetailELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , __ZN13dynamic_arrayIN19TilemapRendererJobs26TilemapRendererGeometryJob4DataELm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _plframe_cursor_thread_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI7Hash128Lm4EE18resize_initializedEm12ResizePolicy , _il2cpp_z__tr_init , __ZN13dynamic_arrayI7SubMeshLm4EE18resize_initializedEmRKS0_12ResizePolicy , _OBJC_IVAR_$_GADNAnimationConfig._initialFrame , _FMOD_vorbis_comment_init , _MadFont_set_initialized_m1716873846 , _MadSprite_get_initialSize_m833555974_MetadataUsageId )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

is there any solution ?

thanks in advance for your reply and comment

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429568/4985585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this issue solved by removing Facebook SDK