# Build Error - symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, armv7

This error shows when I build the Xcode project (the unity build works without errors)

**Xcode Version** 10.0 (10A255)

**Unity:** 2018.1.1f1

**TargetSDK:** DeviceSDK

**Scripting Backend:** IL2CPP

**iOS Version:** target minimum ios 8

**Host OS version:** MacOS 10.13.6

**Error Log**

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>     "__SetStateCallback", referenced from:
>         _ICadeNative__SetStateCallback_m608707758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ICadeNative__SetStateCallback_m608707758)
>     "__GetState", referenced from:
>         _ICadeDeviceManager_Worker_m4279610497 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>         _ICadeNative_GetState_m2566153585 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>         _ICadeNative__GetState_m3529042920 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ICadeNative__GetState_m3529042920)
>     "_SetRoomProperties", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioRoom_m1748957581 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_SetRoomProperties_m3821949182 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_SetRoomProperties_m3821949182)
>     "_SetSourceDirectivity", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioSource_m1250235262 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_SetSourceDirectivity_m4078963299 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_SetSourceDirectivity_m4078963299)
>     "_SetSourceOcclusionIntensity", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioSource_m1250235262 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_SetSourceOcclusionIntensity_m39801839 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_SetSourceOcclusionIntensity_m39801839)
>     "_SetSourceBypassRoomEffects", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioSoundfield_m3904059362 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_SetSourceBypassRoomEffects_m2580524363 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioSource_m1250235262 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_SetSourceBypassRoomEffects_m2580524363)
>     "_CreateSoundfield", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_CreateAudioSoundfield_m2346743101 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_CreateSoundfield_m3129347434 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_CreateSoundfield_m3129347434)
>     "_SetListenerGain", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_UpdateAudioListener_m3171421047 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_SetListenerGain_m1262837316 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_SetListenerGain_m1262837316)
>     "_CreateSoundObject", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_CreateAudioSource_m4135774758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_CreateSoundObject_m4258807046 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_CreateSoundObject_m4258807046)
>     "_Initialize", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_Initialize_m526009310 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_Initialize_m1194042759 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>
> "_GetProfilingInfoCount", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetProfilingInfoCount_m766137662 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetProfilingInfoCount_m766137662)
>     "_SignalFrameEnd", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SignalFrameEnd_m3625945036 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SignalFrameEnd_m3625945036)
>     "_SignalFrameStart", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SignalFrameStart_m935102940 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SignalFrameStart_m935102940)
>     "_ClearTasks", referenced from:
>         _Oni_ClearTasks_m3215281793 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_ClearTasks_m3215281793)
>     "_GetSkinInfo", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetSkinInfo_m3876415578 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetSkinInfo_m3876415578)
>     "_GetSkinnedVertexCount", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetSkinnedVertexCount_m2661974858 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetSkinnedVertexCount_m2661974858)
>     "_Bind", referenced from:
>         _Oni_Bind_m1648480970 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>
> "_GetGroupFromPhase", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetGroupFromPhase_m1410235380 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetGroupFromPhase_m1410235380)
>     "_Generate", referenced from:
>         _Oni_Generate_m707321651 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>
> "_GetHalfEdgeCount", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetHalfEdgeCount_m3807898851 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetHalfEdgeCount_m3807898851)
>     "_GetVertexCount", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetVertexCount_m1527957473 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: __Z48SpriteDataAccessExtensions_CUSTOM_GetVertexCountP12Il2CppObject, __Z79Register_UnityEngine_Experimental_U2D_SpriteDataAccessExtensions_GetVertexCountv , _Oni_GetVertexCount_m1527957473 )
>     "_SetVisualMap", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetVisualMap_m1690096605 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetVisualMap_m1690096605)
>     "_SetNormals", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetNormals_m1265397731 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Mesh_SetNormals_m2521889643_MetadataUsageId, _Mesh_SetNormals_m2521889643 , _Oni_SetNormals_m1265397731 )
>     "_SetFaces", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetFaces_m1855565063 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetFaces_m1855565063)
>     "_SetVertices", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetVertices_m3438414178 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>     "_DestroyHalfEdgeMesh", referenced from:
>         _Oni_DestroyHalfEdgeMesh_m446298859 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyHalfEdgeMesh_m446298859)
>     "_SetDiffuseParticleNeighbourCounts", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDiffuseParticleNeighbourCounts_m2052799446 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDiffuseParticleNeighbourCounts_m2052799446)
>     "_GetDiffuseParticleVelocities", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetDiffuseParticleVelocities_m452956269 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetDiffuseParticleVelocities_m452956269)
>     "_SetDiffuseParticles", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDiffuseParticles_m3571513649 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDiffuseParticles_m3571513649)
>     "_SetDeformableTriangles", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableTriangles_m378752536 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableTriangles_m378752536)
>     "_SetAerodynamicConstraints", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetAerodynamicConstraints_m1100404812 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetAerodynamicConstraints_m1100404812)
>     "_ForceDeformableMeshSkeletalSkinning", referenced from:
>         _Oni_ForceDeformableMeshSkeletalSkinning_m548703253 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_ForceDeformableMeshSkeletalSkinning_m548703253)
>     "_GetMaxSystemConcurrency", referenced from:
>         _ObiProfiler_OnEnable_m81185255 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetMaxSystemConcurrency_m4210831198 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetMaxSystemConcurrency_m4210831198)
>     "_SetActiveConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiStitcher_PushDataToSolver_m839137637 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetActiveConstraints_m2769408721 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>     "_UpdateSkeletalAnimation", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_SimulateStep_m455936664 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_UpdateSkeletalAnimation_m1909247565 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_UpdateSkeletalAnimation_m1909247565)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshBoneTransforms", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshBoneTransforms_m1775815519 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshBoneTransforms_m1775815519)
>     "_DestroySource", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_DestroyAudioSource_m1879126119 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_DestroySource_m60284259 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrAudio_DestroySource_m60284259)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshAnimationData", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshAnimationData_m3565888333 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshAnimationData_m3565888333)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshTBNUpdate", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshTBNUpdate_m2288895058 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshTBNUpdate_m2288895058)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshParticleIndices", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshParticleIndices_m776609164 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshParticleIndices_m776609164)
>     "_DestroyDeformableMesh", referenced from:
>         _Oni_DestroyDeformableMesh_m2999378016 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyDeformableMesh_m2999378016)
>     "__SetActive", referenced from:
>         _ICadeDeviceManager_SetActive_m2492729129 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>         _ICadeNative_SetActive_m466871813 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>         _ICadeNative__SetActive_m2226980393 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ICadeNative__SetActive_m2226980393)
>     "_GetRigidbodyVelocity", referenced from:
>         _ObiRigidbody_UpdateVelocities_m2145059745 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetRigidbodyVelocity_m1495204190 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetRigidbodyVelocity_m1495204190)
>     "_CreateDeformableMesh", referenced from:
>         _Oni_CreateDeformableMesh_m1305789882 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateDeformableMesh_m1305789882)
>     "_SetCollisionMaterials", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetCollisionMaterials_m2626105069 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetCollisionMaterials_m2626105069)
>     "_GetConstraintGroupParameters", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetConstraintGroupParameters_m3754103086 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetConstraintGroupParameters_m3754103086)
>     "_RemoveDeformableTriangles", referenced from:
>         _Oni_RemoveDeformableTriangles_m3355567751 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_RemoveDeformableTriangles_m3355567751)
>     "_GetDeformableTriangleCount", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetDeformableTriangleCount_m3827415252 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetDeformableTriangleCount_m3827415252)
>     "_GetBendingConstraints", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetBendingConstraints_m3652866776 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetBendingConstraints_m3652866776)
>     "_AddParticleExternalForce", referenced from:
>         _Oni_AddParticleExternalForce_m1468539272 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_AddParticleExternalForce_m1468539272, _Oni_AddParticleExternalForces_m969909087 )
>     "_GetSolverParameters", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetSolverParameters_m19832093 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetSolverParameters_m19832093)
>     "_RemoveCollider", referenced from:
>         _Oni_RemoveCollider_m2443317323 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_RemoveCollider_m2443317323)
>     "_UpdateCollisionMaterial", referenced from:
>         _Oni_UpdateCollisionMaterial_m1466698017 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_UpdateCollisionMaterial_m1466698017)
>     "_CreateCollisionMaterial", referenced from:
>         _Oni_CreateCollisionMaterial_m631528853 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateCollisionMaterial_m631528853)
>     "_SetColliderMaterial", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetColliderMaterial_m78085293 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetColliderMaterial_m78085293)
>     "_SetVolumeConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiVolumeConstraintBatch_PushDataToSolver_m2564841872 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetVolumeConstraints_m1704803788 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetVolumeConstraints_m1704803788)
>     "_SetRestPositions", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetRestPositions_m4263406908 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetRestPositions_m4263406908)
>     "_GetTetherConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiTetherConstraintBatch_Cook_m1723962635 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetTetherConstraints_m1394921566 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetTetherConstraints_m1394921566)
>     "_GetBounds", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_CheckVisibility_m1101809153 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetBounds_m1744385772 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ScrollRect_GetBounds_m449872505_MetadataUsageId, _MB_Utility_GetBounds_m517529949 , _MB_Utility_GetBounds_m517529949_MetadataUsageId , _ScrollRect_GetBounds_m449872505 , _Oni_GetBounds_m1744385772 )
>     "_RemoveBatch", referenced from:
>         _ObiStitcher_RemoveFromSolver_m2503851331 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_RemoveBatch_m1012554301 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>     "_SetStitchConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiStitcher_PushDataToSolver_m839137637 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetStitchConstraints_m1051107752 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetStitchConstraints_m1051107752)
>     "_AddParticleExternalForces", referenced from:
>         _ObiSphericalForceZone_ApplyForcesToActor_m134806810 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_AddParticleExternalForces_m969909087 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_AddParticleExternalForces_m969909087)
>     "_EnableBatch", referenced from:
>         _ObiStitcher_OnEnable_m356103258 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_EnableBatch_m1087658715 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiStitcher_OnDisable_m2607718792 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiStitcher_AddToSolver_m1150349560 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_EnableBatch_m1087658715)
>     "_AddCollider", referenced from:
>         _Oni_AddCollider_m3152514427 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_AddCollider_m3152514427)
>     "_GetConstraintCount", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_TriggerFluidUpdateEvents_m1943797781 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetConstraintCount_m1555086262 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSolver_TriggerCollisionEvents_m336768090 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetConstraintCount_m1555086262)
>     "_GetHalfEdgeMeshInfo", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetHalfEdgeMeshInfo_m1877853829 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetHalfEdgeMeshInfo_m1877853829)
>     "_GetActiveConstraintIndices", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_TriggerFluidUpdateEvents_m1943797781 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetActiveConstraintIndices_m3705097581 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetActiveConstraintIndices_m3705097581)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshSkinMap", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshSkinMap_m1520924211 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshSkinMap_m1520924211)
>     "_CreateCollider", referenced from:
>         _Oni_CreateCollider_m1000881537 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateCollider_m1000881537)
>     "_CreateTriangleSkinMap", referenced from:
>         _Oni_CreateTriangleSkinMap_m3407546437 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateTriangleSkinMap_m3407546437)
>     "_GetDistanceConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiDistanceConstraintBatch_Cook_m3238420212 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetDistanceConstraints_m3373950779 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetDistanceConstraints_m3373950779)
>     "_GetParticleVorticities", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_TriggerFluidUpdateEvents_m1943797781 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetParticleVorticities_m4246709086 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetParticleVorticities_m4246709086)
>     "_DestroyTriangleSkinMap", referenced from:
>         _Oni_DestroyTriangleSkinMap_m26316843 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyTriangleSkinMap_m26316843)
>     "_SetColliderRigidbody", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetColliderRigidbody_m1791071819 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetColliderRigidbody_m1791071819)
>     "_GetParticleDensities", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_TriggerFluidUpdateEvents_m1943797781 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetParticleDensities_m3666141959 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetParticleDensities_m3666141959)
>     "_Shutdown", referenced from:
>         _GvrAudio_Shutdown_m1755231902 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>         _GvrAudio_Shutdown_m2350108188 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_3.o
>     "_GetConstraintsOrder", referenced from:
>         _Oni_GetConstraintsOrder_m3544171316 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetConstraintsOrder_m3544171316)
>     "_SetColliderShape", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetColliderShape_m4235395794 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetColliderShape_m4235395794)
>     "_GetRenderableParticlePositions", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_EndFrame_m418284371 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetRenderableParticlePositions_m3423113429 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetRenderableParticlePositions_m3423113429)
>     "_UpdateSolver", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_SimulateStep_m455936664 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_UpdateSolver_m820199541 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_UpdateSolver_m820199541)
>     "_GetSkinConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_Cook_m3189713969 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetSkinConstraints_m2247792247 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_PullDataFromSolver_m2639014144 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetSkinConstraints_m2247792247)
>     "_DestroyBatch", referenced from:
>         _ObiDistanceConstraintBatch_Cook_m3238420212 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_DestroyBatch_m3569985880 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_Cook_m3189713969 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiTetherConstraintBatch_Cook_m1723962635 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyBatch_m3569985880)
>     "_GetBatchPhaseCount", referenced from:
>         _ObiDistanceConstraintBatch_Cook_m3238420212 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetBatchPhaseCount_m1568291772 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_Cook_m3189713969 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiTetherConstraintBatch_Cook_m1723962635 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetBatchPhaseCount_m1568291772)
>     "_AddSimulationTime", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_AccumulateSimulationTime_m1133936819 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_AddSimulationTime_m3974369546 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSolver_Update_m3116953367 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSolver_LateUpdate_m1332329342 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_AddSimulationTime_m3974369546)
>     "_CreateSolver", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_Initialize_m3812045648 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_CreateSolver_m2801536514 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateSolver_m2801536514)
>     "_GetParticlePositions", referenced from:
>         _ObiRope_Tear_m4095819725 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetParticlePositions_m2616934157 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiRopeCursor_AddParticles_m1890904603 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetParticlePositions_m2616934157)
>     "_SetBendingConstraints", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetBendingConstraints_m1998401195 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetBendingConstraints_m1998401195)
>     "_CreateHalfEdgeMesh", referenced from:
>         _Oni_CreateHalfEdgeMesh_m3944992717 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_CreateHalfEdgeMesh_m3944992717)
>     "_SetSkinConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_Cook_m3189713969 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetSkinConstraints_m2442038339 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiSkinConstraintBatch_PushDataToSolver_m1510147647 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetSkinConstraints_m2442038339)
>     "_DestroySolver", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_Teardown_m1967532164 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_DestroySolver_m607864486 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroySolver_m607864486)
>     "_SetParticlePhases", referenced from:
>         _ObiRope_Tear_m4095819725 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetParticlePhases_m2323119324 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetParticlePhases_m2323119324)
>     "_SetInverseOrientations", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetInverseOrientations_m2645908137 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetInverseOrientations_m2645908137)
>     "_UpdateCollider", referenced from:
>         _Oni_UpdateCollider_m4151826442 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>     "_BendingConstraintRest", referenced from:
>         _Oni_BendingConstraintRest_m1954336588 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_BendingConstraintRest_m1954336588)
>     "_DestroyRigidbody", referenced from:
>         _ObiRigidbody_OnDestroy_m4128563384 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_DestroyRigidbody_m2050582037 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyRigidbody_m2050582037)
>     "_SetSolverParameters", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_UpdateParameters_m3537255174 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetSolverParameters_m1856044818 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetSolverParameters_m1856044818)
>     "_GetParticleGrid", referenced from:
>         _ObiParticleGridDebugger_Solver_OnFrameEnd_m2399594836 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_GetParticleGrid_m3201240294 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_GetParticleGrid_m3201240294, _Oni_GetParticleGridSize_m4285915247 )
>     "_SetParticlePositions", referenced from:
>         _ObiEmitter_ResetParticlePosition_m3001502372 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetParticlePositions_m3303496764 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiParticleBaker_PlaybackFrame_m1788289637 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiParticleHandle_Actor_solver_OnFrameBegin_m4048185676 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiRope_Tear_m4095819725 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiRopeCursor_AddParticles_m1890904603 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetParticlePositions_m3303496764)
>     "_SetTetherConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiTetherConstraintBatch_Cook_m1723962635 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetTetherConstraints_m3800618328 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiTetherConstraintBatch_PushDataToSolver_m3640171955 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetTetherConstraints_m3800618328)
>     "_SetHalfEdges", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetHalfEdges_m2161104563 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetHalfEdges_m2161104563)
>     "_SetConstraintsOrder", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_UpdateParameters_m3537255174 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetConstraintsOrder_m1109312545 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetConstraintsOrder_m1109312545)
>     "_DestroyCollisionMaterial", referenced from:
>         _Oni_DestroyCollisionMaterial_m1570566050 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_DestroyCollisionMaterial_m1570566050)
>     "_UpdateRigidbody", referenced from:
>         _ObiRigidbody_UpdateIfNeeded_m2520401889 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_UpdateRigidbody_m2437834328 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ObiColliderBase_UpdateRigidbody_m3691340323, _ObiColliderBase_UpdateRigidbody_m3691340323_MetadataUsageId , _ObiColliderBase_UpdateRigidbody_m3691340323_RuntimeMethod_var , _Oni_UpdateRigidbody_m2437834328 )
>     "_ApplyPositionInterpolation", referenced from:
>         _ObiSolver_EndFrame_m418284371 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_ApplyPositionInterpolation_m95366293 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_ApplyPositionInterpolation_m95366293)
>     "_CreateRigidbody", referenced from:
>         _ObiRigidbody_Awake_m2644499177 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_CreateRigidbody_m11581003 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _ObiColliderBase_CreateRigidbody_m3244494211, _Oni_CreateRigidbody_m11581003 , _ObiColliderBase_CreateRigidbody_m3244494211_MetadataUsageId )
>     "_SetRenderableParticlePositions", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetRenderableParticlePositions_m1894279610 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetRenderableParticlePositions_m1894279610)
>     "_EnableProfiler", referenced from:
>         _ObiProfiler_OnEnable_m81185255 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_EnableProfiler_m2515111239 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiProfiler_OnDisable_m2711410415 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_EnableProfiler_m2515111239)
>     "_SetDistanceConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiDistanceConstraintBatch_Cook_m3238420212 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetDistanceConstraints_m3220181224 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _ObiDistanceConstraintBatch_PushDataToSolver_m3016180836 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDistanceConstraints_m3220181224)
>     "_SetDeformableMeshTransform", referenced from:
>         _Oni_SetDeformableMeshTransform_m809494492 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetDeformableMeshTransform_m809494492)
>     "_SetPinConstraints", referenced from:
>         _ObiPinConstraintBatch_PushDataToSolver_m3745371778 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>         _Oni_SetPinConstraints_m101916813 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_13.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Oni_SetPinConstraints_m101916813)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be any reasons for that , please add the entire error log.
1 reason could be that some files are added / getting compiled multiple times.xcode should give you that filename which might be getting compiled multiple times.You can remove it from project setting -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it seems like some framework(s) is missing that is related to google cardboard SDK. Let me know if it helps.