# How solve 'Undefined symbols for architecture armv7' in React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I get a problem to build release react native ios, I try to look for many examples, but fail all.

**This is the error message :**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_RCTDefaultLogFunction", referenced from:
      -[momsindonesiaTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in momsindonesiaTests.o
  "_RCTSharedApplication", referenced from:
      -[momsindonesiaTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in momsindonesiaTests.o
  "_RCTSetLogFunction", referenced from:
      -[momsindonesiaTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in momsindonesiaTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I don't know how to solve this error again, please help me to solve this problem.**

Thanks.

Comment: Does momsindonesiaTests framework or kind of lib?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: @YucelBayram how to know it is framework or lib ? I'm new user for react native ios

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xcode 10.1 and react native 0.61.5.
To fix try this.

1. Go to project navigator in Xcode
2. Click on the project and go to Build Settings
3. Select 'yourappname'Tests and under Build active Architecture Only   select 'Yes' under Release. By default it is set to 'No'.
4. Try to rebuild and it should build this time round.

Hope this solution works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

`armv7` architecture is stopped supporting by iOS devices from iPhone 5s and today you might not support it as well but the latest iOS SDK still can compile `armv7` for backward compatibility.

To exclude `armv7` from your compilation process you can set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `YES` for all your and React Native targets. This settings enables compiling `arm64` arch for devices and `x86_64` arch for simulators only. For instance, you can add next code to your Podfile to set this settings automatically on `pod install`:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```