# XCode 5 compile library like CMATH

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, objective-c++

I have code contains of Objective-C and C++. I set compiler on "Objective-C++" in "Apple LLVM 5.0 Language - Compile sources as" and now when I want to build application, it tries to compile files like CMATH and CPP_TYPE_TRAILS.H. Do you have any ideas how to figure out this problem? Thank you for answers.

[image]

Comment: I think all you need to do is change your main.m file to main.mm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562255/xcode-m-vs-mm

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your .m file to .mm have a look on this for more info [Mixing Objective-C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710507/mixing-objective-c-and-c)

Comment: Thank you for ideas but it doesn't work. I think that compiler is okey because it compile other C++ classes. When it comes to CMATH then I get error like this "Functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded"

Comment: have you #imported any cmath file in your code or used any cmath function?

Comment: Yes, I guess. I know about it that it compiles all classes and functions. But what I don't know why is why it gets error on standard library function/class.

Comment: Try changing #import <cmath> to #include <cmath>

Comment: are you still getting the same error or it has changed to something else.. also do check for the #import vs #include with other standard library as well

Comment: Thank you for all, I've got it. But I'm not sure where the problem was. I changed .m to .mm files and change compiler then clean project and change 

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

to C++. Then restart XCode and now everything works. Thank you for being patient.