# how to get result from .m function to .mm class Objective-C mixed with Qt

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt

I have Qt application, I'm calling UIImagePickerController to get file path for movie the user selected. So I have static functions in Objective-C which call functions from .m file, when user selects movie I can read selected path in another .m function. Question is, how to get this filePath into some Objective-C class where I can call another Qt classes (like Singleton) and pass this result to proper class ?
Objective-C CL_image_call.mm

```
#include "cl_image_call.h"
#include "cl_image_func.h"

myCLImageClass* CL_image_obj=NULL;

int CL_ImageCCall::CL_objectiveC_Call() {
  //Objective C code calling..... 
    if( CL_image_obj==NULL ) {
      //Allocating the new object for the objective C class we created
        CL_image_obj=[[myCLImageClass alloc]init]; 
    }
  return 1;
}
void CL_ImageCCall::CL_openMedia() {
    [CL_image_obj openMedia];
}
```

CL_image_call.h

```
#include <QImage>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_singleton.h"

class CL_ImageCCall
{
  public:
    static int CL_objectiveC_Call(); 
    static void CL_openMedia();  
};
```

CL_image_func.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface myCLImageClass:NSObject
-(void)openMedia;
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
@end
```

CL_image_func.m

```
#import "cl_image_func.h"

@interface QIOSViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation myCLImageClass
UIImagePickerController *picker=NULL;
UIViewController *viewController=NULL;
NSString *f_path;

-(void)openMedia {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    
    viewController = (UIViewController *)([keyWindow rootViewController]);
        if (!viewController)
            return;
    
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

         picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         picker.delegate = self;
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
         picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

         [viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mov"];
    NSLog (@"File Path = %@", filePath);
    //filePath is what I need to pass to the rest of my app
    
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So in CL_image_call.h I have my "my_singleton" where I can reach my whole app, but how to get filePath to this class ?

Best Regards

Marek

Comment: I guess you need to export the media from album and store in your sandbox somewhere, and you can use the filePath to visit the media and do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to export media:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath =  [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mov"];
    NSLog (@"File Path = %@", filePath);
    //filePath is what I need to pass to the rest of my app
    NSURL *inputURL  = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    // config the session, maybe some option is not what you need, just config by what you need
    AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset
                                                                     presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {
        // do a completion handler
    }];
    
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then you can visit the output by the filePath, and use when you need.

Comment: I wanted to post code in my answer, and comment has too little space, true I could change my original question including your answer but it seemed odd to me

Answer (score 0):

I have modified code with your suggestion and it does what it should. I'm settings moviePath inside my Qt classes and then I call Objective-C code with this path

```
NSString *f_path;
  //Your objective c code here....

-(void)openMedia:(NSString*)moviePath {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    
    f_path=moviePath.copy;
    viewController = (UIViewController *)([keyWindow rootViewController]);
        if (!viewController)
            return;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

         picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         picker.delegate = self;
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
         picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

         [viewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        
    }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *inputURL  = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    // config the session, maybe some option is not what you need, just config by what you need
    AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset
                                                                         presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:f_path];
    session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
    {
        // do a completion handler
        NSLog (@"export complete = %@", f_path);
    }];
    
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

with some trick I can view this movie inside Qt app. One thing that is missing:
I need to know somehow that session has been completed, to refresh file path for MediaPlayer. How can I notify my base class CL_ImageCCall about that. Or actually maybe another Objective-C++ class where I can actually mix Qt and Objective-C ?

Best Regards and thanks for Your help

Marek

Comment: block in exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler is the callback after completed, post a notification or other way to inform your media player, that would be ok

Comment: yes I know this block waits until session is completed. Maybe this is Qt related question. I don't have access from .m file functions to my Qt/C++ classes. If I add something in CL_image_func.h file like #include "my_singleton.h" (my C++ singleton) compilation fails with 20 errors from basic Qt classes. Is there a way for example to use some iOS specific way to notify static class CL_image_call where I initialize CL_image_obj=[[myCLImageClass alloc]init] that imagePicker has finished ?

Comment: also solution for me would be if I could write all iOS code inside .mm files.
Is it possible to move 
-(void)openMedia:(NSString*)moviePath
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
Into .mm files ?

Comment: have you try to make CL_image_func.m rename to CL_image_func.mm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562255/xcode-m-vs-mm

Comment: Thanks man it works excellent after this change. Best Regards